# onEndReached not working properly within any ScrollView React native

Tags: react-native

I am creating a `Listview` with pagination. If i put the `ListView` within `KeyboardAwareScrollView` then `onEndReached` not called properly. But if i don't put the `ListView` within any kind of `Scrollview` it is working perfectly. 
My problem is that the content above the ListView is quite big. If i don't put it entire view within any scrollview the bottom content will not be shown.

How to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't put comment because my rep is below 50.

I'm trying to imagine ur situation based on the description because there's no snapshot of ur desired outcome and current outcome. What I understood is this:

> If i don't put it entire view within any scrollview the bottom content
>   will not be shown

This may be just the problem of not putting {flex:1} in the outtermost container view

> If i put the ListView within KeyboardAwareScrollView then onEndReached
>   not called properly

`ListView` is deprecated as per React Native 0.55 documentation. I don't really understand your scenario, but you might wanna consider just using [Scrollview](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html) or [Flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html), they might have the solution that ur looking for in a different form. If you are looking for a solution so that your view would avoid keyboard, u could simply use [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html) from react native instead of using a third party lib, because sometimes they could be restrictive.

All the best! :)